# Issue with run solana getBalance always returns an error

Tags: solana

This is `balance.js` from the solana development examples:

```js
import { Connection, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, PublicKey,clusterApiUrl  } from "@solana/web3.js";
const connection = new Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com", "confirmed");

const publicKey = new PublicKey('dDCQNnDmNbFVi8cQhKAgXhyhXeJ625tvwsunRyRc7c8');

const balanceInLamports = await connection.getBalance(publicKey);

const balanceInSOL = balanceInLamports / LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;

console.log(
    ` Finished! The balance for the wallet at address ${publicKey} is ${balanceInSOL}!`
);
```

I run it with `node balance.js` - but it always returns this error:

```
\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:7559
      throw new Error('failed to get balance of account ' + publicKey.toBase58() + ': ' + e);
            ^

Error: failed to get balance of account dDCQNnDmNbFVi8cQhKAgXhyhXeJ625tvwsunRyRc7c8: TypeError: fetch failed
    at D:\Develop\Projects\Coin\generate-keypair\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:7559:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.getBalance (D:\Develop\Projects\Coin\generate-keypair\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:7558:12)
    at async file:///D:/Develop/Projects/Coin/generate-keypair/balance.js:7:27

Node.js v20.10.0
```

It seems a network error or return data is not expected. but I has set proxy, if I use a solana tools in cmd line all is run ok, so I can connect to solana's network.

But I in js program, always return error info above.

Or I use `npx esrun balance.ts`, then return:

```
D:\Develop\Projects\Coin\generate-keypair\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:3244
        throw new Error(
              ^

Error: failed to get balance of account dDCQNnDmNbFVi8cQhKAgXhyhXeJ625tvwsunRyRc7c8: TypeError: fetch failed
    at e (D:\Develop\Projects\Coin\generate-keypair\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:3244:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Connection.getBalance (D:\Develop\Projects\Coin\generate-keypair\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:3241:12)
    at <anonymous> (d:\Develop\Projects\Coin\generate-keypairbalance.ts:13:1)

Node.js v20.10.0
```

How I can run solana develop examples without any errors?

Comment: Now I have a America linux server, And I run the code in it, all is ok, no any error reported. So it's strange why in chinese it can't run properly. even I resove the network greatwall.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Next code is run ok, so I think must someting in web3.js is not work.
//And it is a network problem.

import { LAMPORTS_PER_SOL , clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";
import axios from 'axios'
const url = clusterApiUrl("devnet")

const data = {
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: 1,
    method: 'getBalance',
    params: ['CenYq6bDRB7p73EjsPEpiYN7uveyPUTdXkDkgUduboaN',{"encoding": "base58"}]
}
axios.post(url,data,{
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}).then((rsp) => {
    //console.log(rsp.data)
    console.log(rsp.data.result.value/LAMPORTS_PER_SOL)
}).catch((e: any) => {
    console.error(e.message)
    console.log(e.code, e.response.status)
    console.log(e.response.data)
})
```

Comment: Only this could work!

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Connection, PublicKey, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

async function getSOLBalance() {
    const USER_PUBLIC_KEY = new PublicKey("QbxZxLjsHpbM3EZBuwzFCoVWNmQHwLoKjQbBhsCTKJX");
    let aSolanaBalance = await connection.getBalance(USER_PUBLIC_KEY);
    console.log("Solana Balance is:", aSolanaBalance/1000000000);
}

getSOLBalance()
```

This code works perfectly for me in JavaScript. I guess you must have made some error while declaring the connection. If you are using a custom provider for the connection API url, I suggest you check if that provider URL is still active. Try using the `clusterApiUrl` that should solve your issue.

Comment: If you add `import { Connection, PublicKey, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";`  at first line, I can simple use Run code snipet button to Run your code. Then I will found all is ok.

Comment: For some reason I am unable to create a code snippet that can be run by you but you can simply copy the above code and add them to a js file and run it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few minutes ago.
In my case, it was a Node version problem. It wasn't the first time I'm facing some troubles between these versions, so it could be useful to solve another issues too. So, that's the way I solved it:

In the command line, enter the command

```
nvm ls
```

to list all the installed versions of Node in your workstation.

I'm getting something like this. In the picture, v20.1.0 is the default Node version.

[image]

Then, I downgraded the Node version with this command

```
nvm use v18.16.0
```

to choose the second option. Here, you should replace it with your own version. And now it's working!

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering, `TypeError: fetch failed`, typically indicates a network issue, possibly a firewall or connectivity problem preventing your script from accessing the Solana network.

Ensure that your firewall settings allow the script to make outgoing requests. Additionally, verify your internet connection and try running the script again. If you're using a proxy, make sure it's correctly configured for your scripts